# 'Initorcl' file missing

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, installation

I recently installed Oracle 12c on my system on windows10. On `sqlplus " /as sysdba"`
I get connected to an idle instance.
So I executed `startup`. Now I get error

```
SQL> startup
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file 
'C:\ORACLE12C\12C\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\INITORCL.ORA'
```

I checked the path, the `Initorcl` file does not exist at the path.

What is the next step to get this configured?

Comment: Isn't there a `find` command on Windows?

Comment: @Verace searched for it before posting it here... the file does not exist at all .. now what is the way around?

Comment: Did you install the database, too, or did you a software install only? If it was a software only install, you need to create an instance with dbca. Or did you rename the instance to a Name other than ORCL?

Comment: @jmk i did create the db using dbca and named it as 'orcl' but I still get the error...it shows in services as well as running... what next?

Comment: is there anyone else who can solve this for me ... i need to get the database working ... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create new parameter file,search for file alert_orcl.log ,open that file copy all parameters(only lines with "=" signs) after the line "System parameters with non-default values:" to a new file orcl.ora in any location e.g C:\orcl.ora

Next start the database

```
  startup pfile='C:\orcl.ora'; -- if successful go to next step
  create spfile from memory;    --create spfile 
  create pfile='C:\oracle12c\initORCL.ora' from memory --backup pfile
```

Always use rman to backup spfile and controlfiles.

Note:-You'll find alert_orcl.log in ORACLE_BASE\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace(start from diag folder in oracle base directory)